# Python cannot use loadtxt for csv file

Tags: python, numpy

I have an excel spreadsheet with all numbers on it, when I try to open it it gives me error:

```
 for fname in glob.glob("Train*"):

     prob = 0
     a = array(loadtxt(fname, skiprows=1, dtype=object)[prob], dtype=float)
```

ERROR: a = array(loadtxt(fname, skiprows=1, dtype=object)[prob], dtype=float)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I remember this working before but I haven't opened it in a while, not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Could you use `openpyxl` instead?

Comment: Hmm I'll try but not sure how to use that. The reason I use loadtxt is so that I can specify the column later with a[31:50] for example.

Comment: `loadtxt` can't read Excel files.  To use `loadtxt`, you'll have to export the data to a CSV file.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. This is a .csv file.

Answer (score 4):

Break it down.

The first step is to identify the file that is giving you the problem. Insert

```
print fname
```

as the first line inside the loop. The last name it prints before the error is the file in question. 
Then, at the command prompt run

```
loadtxt("thebadfilename", skiprows=1, dtype=object)
```

See what you get.

At about this point you should see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments `numpy.loadtxt` cannot read Excel files.

You could try [`pandas.ExcelFile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#excel-files) to read your data (not sure if this will work as you didn't gave an example.

docstring:

> ```
> Class for parsing tabular excel sheets into DataFrame objects.
> Uses xlrd for parsing .xls files or openpyxl for .xlsx files.
> See ExcelFile.parse for more documentation
>
> Parameters
> ----------
> path : string or file-like object
>     Path to xls file
> kind : {'xls', 'xlsx', None}, default None
> ```